# startWith is returning old value

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm struggling with this for a long time. I simplified the app that I have in my company:

Working stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xewqf9).

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import {map, startWith, takeUntil, tap} from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public visible = false;
  private dateChangedSubj = new Subject();
  public dateChanged$ = this.dateChangedSubj.asObservable();

  private state = {
    date: "11.02.2019"
  };

  public date$;

  constructor() {
    this.date$ = this.dateChanged$.pipe(
      startWith(this.state.date),
    )
  }

  show() {
    this.visible = true;
  }

  hide() {
    this.visible = false;
  }

  changeDate() {
    this.state.date = "12.02.2019";
    this.dateChangedSubj.next(this.state.date);
  }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button (click)="show()">Show</button>
<button (click)="hide()">Hide</button>
<button (click)="changeDate()">Change date</button>

<div *ngIf="visible">
  <p>This one I can hide: {{ date$ | async }}</p>
</div>

<p>This is always visible: {{date$ | async}}</p>
```

I have my configuration stored in a object. In this case it's the `state` object. I store there a simple string value. I can change this value by clicking on `changeDate` button. Then it will change the object's value and also send this new value through `Subject`, so the `view` can be updated. However, if I'm displaying the element after the change occur, the value stays the same.

Steps to reproduce:

- click on `changeDate` button
- the displayed value is correct
- click on `Show` button
- the newly displayed value is the old one, even if the `state` was updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/angular-rxjs-async-pipe-deep-dive-2510b56f793a), it is not recommended to create multiple async pipes for the same observable.
That's because every time you use the async pipe, a new subscription is created as well.

In the snippet below,

```html
<div *ngIf="visible">
  <p>This one I can hide: {{ date$ | async }}</p>
</div>
```

a new subscription will be created when `visible = true`.
And because you have this in your code

```js
this.date$ = this.dateChanged$.pipe(
 startWith(this.state.date),
 tap(v => console.log('emitted state value', v)), // The previous value
)
```

it will emit the previous value of `this.state.date`.

You can also see that a new subscription is created every time when you show the date again.

Here is a solution, that will make sure that we use the async pipe **only once** on a given observable.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(date$ | async) as date">
  <div *ngIf="visible">
    <p>This one I can hide: {{ date }}</p>
  </div>

  <p>This is always visible: {{ date }}</p>

</ng-container>
```

With this approach, only one subscription is created.

[Here is a StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h5imjy?file=src/app/app.component.html).
Also, make sure you check the console so you can get a better understanding of what's going on.(That's how I actually solved the problem)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject` and you won't need `startWith`. This way you will have last emitted value and it will always be actual.

Link to updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h6dk7h

Comment: I know that `BehaviorSubject` will work, but I can't change the implementation. I just want to understand why this way the value is not updated.

Comment: Because every time you hide and re-add the piece of code hidden by `ngIf` you create a new Subscription and it should `startWith` some value which you defined. If  you will hide it with `[hidden]="!visible"` it will work the way you want.